# Как в svg добавить тень изображению. В самом svg файле. Статика

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, веб-дизайн

Подскажите как в svg добавить тень изображению или к базовым фигурам svg.

В самом svg файле.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3

Comment: Если надо добавить тень в векторный SVG файл, то надо пользоваться графическим векторным редактором (например Illustrator).

Comment: @abris в файл svg проще добавлять через код, а не рисовать в редакторе

Answer (score 2):

Один из способов получения тени внутри файла svg - добавить svg фильтр

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%"  width="150%" height="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feOffset in="blur" dx="3" dy="3" result="offsetBlur"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="offsetBlur"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <rect class="rect1" x="5" y="5" width="50" height="50" fill="greenyellow" filter="url(#drop-shadow)" /> 
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="purple" filter="url(#drop-shadow)" />
  
 <svg>
```